# touchesMoved no longer triggers after changing UIView to UIScrollView?

Tags: xcode, uiview, uiscrollview, touchesmoved

I had a UIView with lots of objects. I also had an implementation of touchesMoved like this:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"move");
}
```

I recently wanted the view to scroll, so I simply opened up the UIView, and in Interface Builder changed its object class to UIScrollView. However, now the 'touchesMoved' method is never called even when I touch the screen.

Can someone please help me get touchesMoved working again? I'm not sure what I did to break it!

EDIT: I tried following [this guide](http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/detect-single-tap-in-uiscrollview.html) but I might've done something wrong. From reading other posts it seems like UIScrollView can't accept touch events itself, and they need to be sent up the responder chain? I will be extremely grateful for anyone who can help guide me through this problem... my app was just about ready for submission when I realized the UIScrolView killed my touch detection! (I just changed my apps UIView to UIScrollView to allow compatibility with iPhone 4).

Comment: Your question looks similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259005/uiscrollview-with-touchesmoved-not-called). Perhaps one of the suggestions there might work for you?

Comment: Thanks for the link. They recommend setting _mainScroller.delaysContentTouches=NO; and _mainScroller.canCancelContentTouches=NO;  I've doen both of these and my touches are still not being detected at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just took a look at [the guide](http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/detect-single-tap-in-uiscrollview.html) in your edit, and I think I can see the problem. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12367339/1367622) on a similar question.

Your `UIScrollView` subclass will look something like this:

```
#import "AppScrollView.h"

@implementation AppScrollView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    return [super initWithFrame:frame];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"AppScrollView touchesEnded:withEvent:");

    // If not dragging, send event to next responder
    if (!self.dragging)
        [[self.nextResponder nextResponder] touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    else
        [super touchesEnded: touches withEvent: event];

}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"AppScrollView touchesMoved:withEvent:");

    [[self.nextResponder nextResponder] touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

@end
```

And your class that includes the `AppScrollView` object should adopt the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol and implement these methods:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"SomeClass touchesMoved:withEvent:");
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"SomeClass touchesEnded:withEvent:");
}
```

Then the logged output will look like this:

```
2013-06-11 10:45:21.625 Test[54090:c07] AppScrollView touchesMoved:withEvent:
2013-06-11 10:45:21.625 Test[54090:c07] SomeClass touchesMoved:withEvent:
2013-06-11 10:45:21.642 Test[54090:c07] AppScrollView touchesMoved:withEvent:
2013-06-11 10:45:21.642 Test[54090:c07] SomeClass touchesMoved:withEvent:
2013-06-11 10:45:21.655 Test[54090:c07] AppScrollView touchesEnded:withEvent:
2013-06-11 10:45:21.656 Test[54090:c07] SomeClass touchesEnded:withEvent:
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply... I'll give it a try after work today and report back!

Comment: Hmmmmm. It works. Though with single nextResponder call it did not work. Any idea why this is?