# How to setup a subclass of UIScrollView to respond to touch events?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I recently had a problem regarding not being able to register touches events (`touchesMoved`, etc) from within a `UIScrollView`. After talking with lots of people and reading tons of posts, it turns out `UIScrollView` does't accept touches itself, and instead the touches need to be passed to a `UIScrollView` subclass.

I am very new to objective-c, and am having a terrible time wrapping my head around how subclasses are defined (in separate .h/.m files or somehow in @interface or something), as well as how iOS deals with responder chains.

Please let me describe my exact situation, and anyone willing to explain what I need to do in noob-speak will be really appreciated.

I have a single page in my app, and I changed it's default `UIView` to `UIScrollView`, so if I inspect it in `InterfaceBuidler` all I see is my `SampleViewController` and `UIScrollView`. I linked my `UIScrollView` to the `@Interface` of `SampleViewControler.h` like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface SampleViewController : UIViewController
{
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *mainScroller;
@end
```

And I referenced my `UIScrollView`  in `SampleViewController.m` like this:

```
#import "SampleViewController.h"
@interface SampleViewController ()
@end

@implementation SampleViewController
@synthesize mainScroller = _mainScroller;

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"Movement!");
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [_mainScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0) animated:YES];
}
```

If I change the class of `UIScrollView` to `UIView`, the touches are detected and I fire off a few `NSLog` messages. However, once `UIView` is set back to `UIScrollView`, touches are ignored.

From what I understand I need to setup a subclass of `UIScrollView` with the code:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"Movement!");
}
```

...and then change my SampleViewController.m to have the code:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [[self.nextResponder nextResponder] touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

However, I really don't understand 1) how to setup such a subclass, and 2) why this would work, since I don't see why `[[self.nextResponder nextResponder] touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];` would ever be called in the first place from within `SampleViewController.m`, since my similar `NSLog(@"Movement!");` statement is never executed.

I have tried every tutorial I could find, and am turning toward to the expertise of SE! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're thinking about this wrong. If you want to know when a scrollView is moving, there's no need to subclass it. iOS has set up all the methods you need inside of the `UIScrollViewDelegate`. IF however you want to say, pick up touchEvents for items based inside the scrollView, then that is perfectly okay. You need to then just subclass the items inside the scrollView and pick up the touchEvents inside the respective classes though. But for just standard scrollView methods you should set it up as so:

.H

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
  @interface SampleViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>
  {
  }
  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *mainScroller;
  @end
```

.M

```
#import "SampleViewController.h"

@interface SampleViewController ()
@end

@implementation SampleViewController
@synthesize mainScroller = _mainScroller;

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   self.mainScroller.delegate=self;//Adopt the delegate for the scrollView..this is the important line
}
```

Then just implement the UIScrollViewDelegateMethods to grab movement etc. Undefined behavior will occur when trying to pick up touchEvents inside a scrollView/tableView, since the scrollView itself already implements those touchEvents behind the scenes

Look at all the methods on the Developer site and implement them in your .M file. Since you've adopted the delegate in viewDidLoad, these will be your scrollView call backs. I've listed a few of them before but go ahead and look on the [UIScrollViewDelegate Protocol site](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate.html)

```
– scrollViewDidScroll:
– scrollViewWillBeginDragging:
– scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:
– scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:
– scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:
– scrollViewDidScrollToTop:
– scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:
– scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:
```

Comment: Hi @ttarules, thanks for your thoughtful answer, but I guess I wasn't clear in my question:  I am not trying to detect the scrolling... Instead, when I user touches the screen and moves around a little, but not enough to scroll, I want to detect that. The scrolling is just so the user can access some hidden settings beyond the main body of the welcome screen.

Comment: To be more specific, imagine there is a horizontal keyboard in my app. There are additional settings below that the user can scroll to, but while the keyboard is in view I want them to be able to swipe across the keys and have the x&y coordinates of every touch event so I can programmatically respond to them.

Comment: Haha cool. Funny timing on the comment cuz I just edited my answer to address something like that. Look at the top where I speak about the items inside of your scrollView. Basically you would need to pick up the touchEvents inside the subclassed views that are contained in the scrollView.. Does that make sense?

Comment: Haha, I just saw your edit as soon as I posted my comment. Thanks for the additional contribution! So, the problem is I don't quite undestand how to do this: "You need to then just subclass the items inside the scrollView and pick up the touchEvents inside the respective classes though."   However, I perfectly understand your IUScrollViewDelegate answer, and am sure I will find a time to use it in the future!

Comment: Well it's pretty dependent upon whatever is contained inside of your scrollView and whether or not you have paging enabled. Whats the actual purpose of having the scrollView?

Comment: Hmmm, not sure what paging is. I have several images, buttons, text labels, and segmented buttons (as well as the virtual keyboard) all in this UIScrollView. Everything was actually in a UIView, and was working great, but I realized for iPhone4 support I needed the app to scroll so that iPhone4 users would have access to the options at the bottom of the app (the app was designed with iPhone 5 in mind). So, I changed the UIView to UIScrollView, but that broke my touchesMoved methods. I think all I would have to subclass is touchesMoved?

Answer (score 0):

I posted an answer to a similar question a few days ago that might help you as well. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015819/touchesmoved-no-longer-triggers-after-changing-uiview-to-uiscrollview/) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17034972/1367622).

It looks like you're close to getting it working, but you've gotten a bit confused about where to put the `touchesMoved` methods.

In your subclass of `UIScrollView`, you should have:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [[self.nextResponder nextResponder] touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

And in your `SampleViewController.m` file:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"Movement!");
}
```

(You have these two around the other way in your question.)